# What is the purpose of dereferencing eax when it contains 0?

Tags: assembly, x86

How can the following instructions make any sense?

```
xor eax,eax
mov eax,[eax]
```

When you XOR eax, you get zero most of the time, so can you dereference what is at address [eax] (in this case eax contains 0) and put it back into eax?

Comment: When would 'xor eax,eax' not zero eax?

Comment: @MartinJames I was a noob. I'm still a noob.  Do you expect anything else from a noob? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did this code come from? And what OS is it intended to run on?

I see two possibilities:

1. This code is supposed to generate an intentional segmentation fault.
2. The code is intended to run on a system where there is a valid page at address 0, and it's trying to access whatever is there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want clarified.

```
xor eax, eax
```

Will generate 0 *always*.

dereferencing 0 will most often result in a page fault. That is, unless there is a valid page at address 0...